# Error con los controladores en CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Comencé hace unos días con el framework CodeIginiter, para la instalación y configuración utilice la documentación oficial. Seguí cada uno de sus pasos y "funciono" de cierta manera. Pero tengo unos problemas si intento acceder a la ruta por defecto con el nombre de un controlador, este no puede encontrarlo, por ejemplo `localhost/TesisSuprema/inicioController/index` 
o `localhost/TesisSuprema/loginController` en ambos casos me dice que, la ruta no es la correcta y no se encontro nada.

[image: ,]

Hasta ahí todo bien, sin embargo, tengo algunas dudas las cuales aun no he podido disipar:

- Cuando intento llamarla por el nombre del controlador (he visto en muchos ejemplos, lo manejan de esta forma) a mi me genera error.
- A la hora de que intento hacer clic en la parte donde dice "Iniciar sesion", uso un `base_url()` y hago la llamada a mi siguiente controlador, el que muestra la vista del login `loginController.php` pero, este me marca error, diciendo que no lo encuentra.

Explicando ya un poco el contexto y el problema, muestro mis clases y la estructura del código:

Mi estructura general (carpetas, etc..)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el archivo `config.php` modifique los apartados

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/TesisSuprema/';

$config['index_page'] = '';
```

En `autoload.php`

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

En `routes.php`

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'inicioController';
$route['404_override'] = 'error404';
```

Mi `inicioController.php`

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

/* Definiendo el primer controller para el inicio */
class inicioController extends CI_Controller{

    public function index(){
        $this->load->view('/templates/inicio');
    }
}
```

mi vista `inicio.php`

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
?>


<!-- Comiendo del html -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>S.O.R.D.O.S Index</title>

    <!-- Librerias de Bootstap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= base_url('bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css'); ?>"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js'); ?>"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('bootstrap/css/inicio.css'); ?>"/>
    <!-- Iconos -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a296fa0db7.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand">
            <div class="container"><a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Bienvenido(a)</a><button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navcol-1" class="navbar-toggler"></button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navcol-1">
                    <ul class="nav  ml-auto">
                        <li role="presentation" class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link"><span class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"> Iniciar Sesion</a></span></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <ol id="pan"class="breadcrumb ">
        <li class="breadcrumb-item active"><a><span>Inicio</span></a></li>
    </ol>

    <section id="main">
        <div class="container">
            <div  class="row"> <!-- Filas General div-->
                <div id="alumnos" class="row"> <!-- Primera Fila -->
                <div class=" col-md-4" > 
                    <h2 class="text-center">Objetivos para los alumnos</h2>
                    <p class="text-justify">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum ea laudantium accusantium necessitatibus dignissimos sapiente quos, 
                        dicta quisquam id ducimus recusandae nesciunt hic, culpa repellendus quaerat dolor optio similique reiciendis.</p>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-1">
                    <div id="" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                        <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/KZVTziJ9hg4" frameborder="0"></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>


                <div id="alumno" class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 ">
                        <h2 class="text-center">Objetivo para el alumno</h2>
                        <p class="text-justify">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum ea laudantium accusantium necessitatibus dignissimos sapiente quos, 
                            dicta quisquam id ducimus recusandae nesciunt hic, culpa repellendus quaerat dolor optio similique reiciendis.</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-1">
                        <div id="" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                            <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/nlDdqAIDk2A" frameborder="0"></iframe>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </section>



</body>
</html>
```

En mi otro controller, `loginController.php`

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

/* Definiendo el primer controller para el inicio */
class loginController extends CI_Controller{

    public function index(){
        $this->load->view('/templates/login');
    }
```

Y hacia la otra vista que deseo rediregir es `login.php`

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
?>

<!-- Comienzo del HTML -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

    <!-- Librerias de Bootstap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= base_url('bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css'); ?>"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js'); ?>"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('bootstrap/css/inicio.css'); ?>"/>
    <!-- Iconos -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a296fa0db7.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>Aqui debe haber una redireccio</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Actualización, falto agregar los `.htaccess` que uso. El primero se encuentra en directorio raíz del framework:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.cs> 
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|css|js|images|bootstrap)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

El segundo se cuentra en la carpeta `application/.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No vi por ninguna parte tu edición del .htaccess que hace no tener que escribir `index.php` previo a ingresar a cualquier controlador y a su método por defecto.

Si no configuras este .htaccess siempre vas a tener que incluir un `index.php` previo a tus llamadas, ejemplo usando tu configuración:

Error:

```
localhost/TesisSuprema/inicioController/index
```

Correcto:

```
localhost/TesisSuprema/index.php/inicioController/index
```

Si no lo haces de la manera correcta `codeigniter` jamás encontrará tu controlador. Para revietir este efecto, es necesario que configures dos `.htaccess`

1. El primero, es el que está dentro de tu raíz del proyecto, este debe de contener lo siguiente:

---

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt|public)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
SetEnvIf Authorization .+ HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$0
```

2. El segundo `.htaccess` será el que está dentro de tu carpeta `application` y debe de ser así:

---

```
<IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
```

Esto deberá permitir ingresar al método por defecto dentro del controlador `inicioController` de la siguiente manera:

```
localhost/TesisSuprema/inicioController/index
```

Aunque, si necesitas que entre por defecto al método `index` debes decirle en tu `routes.php` lo siguiente:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'inicioController';
$route[''] = 'inicioController/index';
```

Al decirle que `$route[''] = 'inicioController/index` significa que cuando codeigniter detecte una ruta sin a dónde ir como `localhost/TesisSuprema` sabrá que por defecto irá no solo a `inicioController` sino que también todo lo que venga vacío después de `tesisSuprema/` será dirigido al método `index` de tu controlador `inicioController`

Con lo anterior explicado aclaro tus dos dudas, es importante conocer más sobre cómo funciona el [`routes.php`](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html) de codeigniter para poder saber distribuir las direcciones de tu aplicativo.

Comment: Gracias por la observación, no me había percatado que omití los htaccess que uso. el que esta en `application/.htaccess` es el por defecto. No modifique nada. El segundo, el cual esta en la raíz de la carpeta, lo cree con base a la documentación que maneja codeigniter.

Los use de esta manera porque, tenia un pequeño inconveniente con bootstrap, de cierta manera ignoraba las rutas de los archivos, dando un error 404 "ruta no encontrada".

Comment: Espero que te haya solucionado el problema mi respuesta

Comment: Si me ayudo en corregirlo, gracias viejo.